# Инкремент поля MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Задача**

В зависимости от полученного GET запроса нужно инкрементировать поле в БД.

**Проблема**

Не работает мой код )) Ошибок нет.

**РHP**

```html
<?php    

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$name = $_GET["name"];

$query = "UPDATE `rating` WHERE `name`='$name' SET `votes` = `votes` + 1";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Без сообщения об ошибке, можно только гадать, что не так.

Comment: @Алекс Вы бы на ошибки в запросе проверяли и если есть печатали бы текст mysql_error()

Comment: Была ошибка в запросе. Помог Rikaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE `rating` SET `votes` = `votes` + 1 WHERE `name`='$name'";
```

Оператор **WHERE** должен идти после оператора **SET**
см. [Синтаксис Update запроса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81)

Comment: @Алекс, благодарность можно выразить отметив мой ответ как правильный)

Comment: Жду окончание счётчика )